# Overriding protected methods in Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I have a class which implements an abstract class. The abstract class has a `protected virtual` method as shown:

```
protected virtual void OnAction(string action, object result);
```

The class implementing the abstract class has a method which when completed calls `base.OnAction`.

I am trying to override the behaviour of the implementation of OnAction in my unit tests as I am trying to unit test only, not do integration tests.

My Moq call is setup as follows:

```
mock.Protected().Setup("OnAction", ItExpr.IsAny<string>, ItExpr.IsAny<object>());
```

Breakpointing my base abstract classes `OnAction` method confirms it is still being called.

I'm essentially wanting Moq to do the equivalent in it's emitted class:

```
public override OnAction(string action, object result) { // do nothing }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd expect different, you're mocking a method that is never invoked in your concrete implementation.

What you have currently looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Derple
{
    protected virtual void OnAction(string action, object result) { Console.WriteLine("Derple"); }
}

public class Herple : Derple
{
    public void DoTheHerple(string action, object result) { base.OnAction(action, result); }
}
```

So by mocking the `Herple` `OnAction` method you're mocking something that's never invoked, since the concrete `DoTheHerple` call is *still* invoking the base class implementation.

An ugly way around this is to override the method in your child class, and invoke the base class method there, and then invoke `this.OnAction` in your child class method.

```
public abstract class Derple
{
    protected virtual void OnAction(string action, object result) { Console.WriteLine("Derple"); }
}

public class Herple : Derple
{
    protected override void OnAction(string action, object result) { base.OnAction(action, result); }
    public void DoTheHerple(string action, object result) { this.OnAction(action, result); }
}
```

This will make your test function as you're wanting, but it's arguably indicative of a flaw in your design that it's necessary.

*Edit

As Matthew pointed out, the override isn't actually necessary for this to work.

```
public class Herple : Derple
{
    public void DoTheHerple(string action, object result) { OnAction(action, result); }
}
```

works as well.

Comment: I believe you should be able to do `OnAction` without specifying `base` nor `this`, or even overriding it.

Comment: @Matthew Misunderstood your intention initially, you're right, just invoking `OnAction` lets the mock work as described, without specifying the override in the child class.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot thanks for your answer and it made me realise what I was actually doing wrong; I was calling base.OnAction as opposed to OnAction.

Comment: The question is: Does the derived class `Herple` override the virtual method `OnAction` itself? Because if it does not, why did it use the syntax `base.OnAction(...)` instead of simply `this.OnAction(...)` or `OnAction(...)`? I think people use the `base` keyword too much sometimes. As a rule of thumb, don't use `base` if you can avoid it.